# Expected value of dice tossing problem

Tags: probability, expected-value

The following is an interview question by Jane Street.

> Let's play a game - I give you a $12$ sided die and will pay you whatever the die lands on. If you are unhappy with the roll, you can choose to roll another two 6-sided dice and I will pay you the sum of the two dice. How much are you willing to pay to play this game.

My attempt:

Since the expected value of the sum of two $6$-sided dice is $7,$ we should roll again if we get $\leq 7$ from the $12$-sided dice.
Therefore, the expected value is 
$$\frac{21}{36}\times 7 + \frac{5}{36}\times 8 + \frac{4}{36}\times 9 + \frac{3}{36}\times 10 + \frac{2}{36}\times 11 + \frac{1}{36}\times 12  \approx 7.972.$$

However, according to [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.sg/Interview/Let-s-play-a-game-I-give-you-a-12-sided-die-and-will-pay-you-whatever-the-die-lands-on-If-you-are-unhappy-with-the-roll-QTN_216680.htm), the answer seems to be $8.25.$

I have no idea where I go wrong in my calculations above.

Comment: The expected value of a single die is $3.5$, hence the expected value of the sum of two fair dice is $7$

Comment: @lulu Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Comment: Your calculation does not make sense.  Since the first roll involves a $12-$sided die, not a pair of ordinary dice, your probabilities are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a $6/12$ chance of rolling under $7$, and then a $6/12$ to roll the average of $7,8,9,10,11$ and $12$. I.e. the expected result is
$$7\frac{6}{12}+\frac{7+8+9+10+11+12}{6}\frac{6}{12}=8.25$$

Comment: I do not understand the average of $7,8,9,10,11,12$. Why do we need to calculate it?

Comment: Because if we don't roll below $7$, then we roll either $7,8,9,10,11$ or $12$. So when we roll $\ge 7$ we would on average roll a 9.5. But there is a $6/12$ chance of rolling $\ge 7$, so the expected value when rolling $\ge 7$ is $9.5\cdot 6/12$